# What type of mineral is this?

Tags: rocks, mineralogy, minerals

My grandfather found this thing.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science StackExchange! Please follow the directions in: http://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions to improve the quality of your question and also improve the chances of it getting answered.

Comment: Voting to close for now, but will gladly vote to re-open if the requested details are added.

Comment: Might be an eclogite (red being garnet and green being omphacite)

Answer (score 1):

The green material indicates the potential presence of copper & the shiny bits on the lower left & mid right of the specimen look metallic, but that could be just glint in the picture.

Also, there are two groves on the lower right which may indicate a soft metal like copper.

If it is metallic it could be native copper or it could be lump of copper from a foundry.

Comment: The two indentations on the right were created by a shovel perhaps, So it would have to be a soft metal and when copper ionizes it will look turquoise in color similar to this sample.So I agree with Fred, Copper. But these are only guesses, follow the link Artexabelta posted so a more persice answer will be generated.